# integer is not rendering in textbox in react native

Tags: react-native

By default, i am getting the textbox value from `props` that value is an integer, to convert that into string I am using `.toString()` method to display the TextBox `defaultValue` but its throwing error `.toString` is undefined. My code is

```
const { menuDetails } = this.props;
<TextInput
    returnKeyType='done'
    keyboardType = 'number-pad'
    maxLength ={6}
    defaultValue={menuDetails.price.toString()}
    onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({value})}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextInput
    returnKeyType='done'
    keyboardType = 'number-pad'
    maxLength ={6}
    defaultValue={`${menuDetails.price}`}
    onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({value})}
/>
```